# Strange Cube Root Offense in an Inequality

Tags: inequality, summation, proof-writing, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I don't know how to tackle the unusual cube root present in this inequality-
$1.$For real numbers $a,b,c > 0$ and $n\le3$ prove that
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+n\left(\frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}\right)\ge 3+n$$
Here is another question with the same lesser side (and of course I couldn't prove)-
$2.$Let $a, b, c$ be positive real numbers such that $a + b + c = ab + bc + ca$
and $n ≤ 3$. Prove that
$$\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{a}+\frac{3n}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\ge 3+n$$
What I attempted was this-
$$\left(a+b+c\right)\left(\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{a}+\frac{3n}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\right)\ge \left(a+b+c\right)\left(3+n\right)$$
Avoiding the RHS for some time-
$$\left(a+b+c\right)\left(\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{a}+\frac{3n}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\right)\ge (a+b+c)^2+\frac{3n(a+b+c)}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$
After this step I don't know where to use $a+b+c=ab+bc+ca$.
These are very basic. I need a solution using AM-GM Inequality.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "offense"?

Comment: Can you prove it for $n = 3$? If yes, showing it for $ n \leq 3$ is obvious.

Comment: To elaborate on @CalvinLin's comment, you want to use mathematical induction. That is, proof it works for one case (in this case $n=3$). Then assume it works up to $k$ for some $k \ge 3$ and proof that if this is true, then it must also be true for $k + 1$. By this you prove it is true for 3, and by recursion every other integer greater than 3

Comment: @CalvinLin which of the two? I want to use AM-GM Inequality, because I'm uncomfortable using mathematical induction.

Comment: I have a proof for $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{24\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}\geq11,$ but it's not AM-GM

Comment: It seems that the second inequality is true for any  $n\leq5$, for which it's enough to prove it for $n=5$ (if it's true, I see how we can prove it),  but it's not AM-GM again.

Comment: I think for little $n$ these inequalities are not so strong and it's possible to find  solutions by AM-GM.

Comment: I can't get it if it is related to convex functions, but I'm good with rearrangement, chebishev, cauchy schwarz and power mean, so a solution using these can be provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The first inequality for $n=3$.

By AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b}+\frac{9\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{2a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}\right)+\frac{9\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}\geq$$
$$\geq\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^2}{b^2}\cdot\frac{b}{c}}+\frac{9\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+b+c}{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}+\frac{9\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}\geq$$
$$\geq6\sqrt[6]{\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}\right)^3\left(\frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}\right)^3}=6.$$

Comment: Brilliant! But how to prove it for $n \le 3$?

Comment: @Book Of Flames It's obvious by AM-GM

Comment: And the second one?

Comment: @Book Of Flames I have fined something nice. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: Wait, it will take me some time to write, I'm not perfected at using MathJax

Comment: See, I have added something.

Answer (score 1):

A proof for $n=3$ of the second one.

By AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{9}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\geq2\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b}\cdot\frac{9}{a^2+b^2+c^2}}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b}\geq a^2+b^2+c^2$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b}\sum_{cyc}ab\geq\sum_{cyc}a^2\sum_{cyc}a$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4c^2-a^3c^2b)\geq0,$$ which is true by AM-GM again:
$$\sum_{cyc}a^4c^2=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{cyc}\left(4a^4c^2+b^4a^2+c^4b^2\right)\geq\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[6]{(a^4c^2)^4\cdot b^4a^2\cdot c^4b^2}=\sum_{cyc}a^3c^2b.$$

Comment: I suggest to check out the mistake in the last expression.

Comment: @Book Of Flames Yes, it was typo. I fixed.